# how to pass a list into postgres as a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to run this with typeorm

```
const fields = await queryRunner.query(
  `SELECT "fieldId", "name" FROM "field" WHERE "name" IN ($1) `,
  [...fieldNames]
);
```

where fieldNames is a list. But I get an error saying  `bind message supplies 5 parameters`

Is there anyway to make this dynamic so i can pass a list and get returned values? This isn't unique to type orm -- it's an issue with postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of an `IN` query is a separate parameter. If you want to pass five elements you need five parameters.

```
SELECT "fieldId", "name"
FROM "field"
WHERE "name" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)
```

This means dynamically generating the SQL to match the number of values you have.

---

Postgres offers a better way. Use the [`any` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME). This works with an array which is a single value.

```
SELECT "fieldId", "name"
FROM "field"
WHERE "name" = ANY($1)
```

Now you should be able to pass an array of values *as your first parameter*. Typeorm should convert it to a [Postgres Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html).

```
const sql = `
  select fieldId, name
  from field
  where name = ANY($1)
`
const values = [['manny','moe','jack']]
client.query(sql, values)
```

This should result in:

```
  select fieldId, name
  from field
  where name = ANY(ARRAY['manny','moe','jack'])
```